# Search strings in a single column of a tsv file in python

Tags: pandas

I have a list as follows.

```
mylist=['code1', 'code5', 'code11']
```

I also have a tsv file with the column headings -> `id`, `quantity_details`, `ingredients`

```
id  quantity_details    ingredients
code1   tim tam 5, sugar 500g   recipe of code 1 here. 
code2   milk 2L, sugar 250g eggs 5     recipe of code 2 here.
```

Now, I want to search the codes in `mylist` in only the `id` column of the tsv file, and return the corresponding `quantity_details` and `ingredients` values as a single string. i.e. the string of `code1` should be = `<corresponding quantity_details value>`. `<corresponding ingredients value>`

Expected output:

```
mystrings = [string for code1, string for code5, string for code11]
```

Can we do this using pandas in python?

Comment: Please produce an [mcve] with expected output. Can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ edited the question :) Please let me know if it is clear now?

Comment: You haven't given me what I asked - 5-10 rows of your data and expected output.

Comment: I think you're looking for `v = df.loc[df.id.isin(mylist)]; print(v.quantity_details + '.' + v.ingredients)` But I can't confirm that without your data and expected output.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks! that works :)

Comment: I’d like to post an answer. Where is your data? This is the third time I’m asking.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ updated the question :)